# Is renaming schemas more efficient / faster than drop/create in a single transaction

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-10

Given the constraint (from customer side) to having only one *database* - how can I most effectively deploy new versions of data into a production-facing application.

The new data is packaged into a (`-Fc`) dump file. This data is supposed to *replace* the existing data, so restoring it must be done by first dropping the existing tables and then restoring the new ones.

The naive approach of just importing the dump file with `pg_restore` with `--single-transaction` will lock the whole database which will cause the application dependent on that data to halt/suspend queries.

My intended approach is to utilize schemas. Basically, the application will have set its connection string to use `mydb.public`. The import imports all new data into `mydb.next`.

Then, rename `mydb.public` to `mydb.old`, rename `mydb.next` to `mydb.public` and drop `mydb.old`.

Would this approach result in a shorter downtime than importing directly? I am not sure how renames of schemas work internally in postgres, but from my surface understanding, it should be a more efficient approach

Comment: I don't think `--single-transaction` will "lock the whole database". To my knowledge it only locks the tables that are being dropped.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name even so - during the restore of that table it will be unavailable for the application. with renaming, I expect (hope?) that time will be reduced compared to the transactional approach

Comment: If you rename the schema where the "active" tables are, those are unavailable to the application as well (unless you can change the search path for the databases user during the import)

Comment: Correct, but the overall operation should be faster because I don't need to wait for the data to be written..?

Comment: From my understanding its easy enough to test against your backend technology to see if implies undesired side effects like connections drops o unexpected locks. Special care on the search_path

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that creating a new schema and later renaming it will be faster than dropping the tables and re-creating them, but it will certainly reduce the time during which the data are not available to the user.

Note that you have to cancel all other transactions and prevent users from starting new ones when you drop the old schema, otherwise `DROP SCHEMA oldschema CASCADE` will block until all concurrent transactions are done.

Comment: That's a good hint, thank you. I'm working on creating a local test setup to see the different methods in action.